# Trying to start a cron job on serversfree

Tags: cron, cron-task

I'm trying to add a cron job on my server, that is hosting here http://partisscan.bugs3.com/.
The provider for that is serversfree http://www.serversfree.com.

It is realy good but i can't make a cron job. I want my php file http://partisscan.bugs3.com/scan.php to be started every minute(maybe latter less often but for start). So i added a cron job in a cron job manager under control panel but it's not working.
my cron job is:

```
 1 * * * *  php -f /home/u798416153/scan.php
```

However it's not working:S

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for not working.

Regarding the file:

- Executing permissions of the file.
- Owner of the file.

Regarding the crontab:

- To which user does this crontab correspond the line you posted?
- Does it have to be executed by root or any other user? If it is not root, you have to make sure that the user is not in /etc/cron.d/deny.

Comment: Thank u werry much i didn't have permissions on file set corectly, i set to 777 and now it works fine!